# Ratchet PHP - Push messaging service

Tags: javascript, php, phpwebsocket, ratchet

Most of the examples I'm looking at with Ratchet are for chat services, and I'm currently building an application where the user logs in and receives notifications from the server based on their user ID.

I have the basic tutorials working, however I'm struggling to understand a few points:

When the `onOpen()` method is called, I set the `$conn` object into an array like so:

```
$this->clients[$conn->resourceId]['conn'] = $conn;
```

In my Javascript, within the `onopen` function I also send a JSON payload with the `send` function. My server pics this up and stores it like so, in the `onMessage` method:

```
$this->clients[$conn->resourceId]['json'] = $json;
```

So now I have my connected users stored in an array, **how do I send a message to a specific user?** I've looked into `onSubscribe` and the `broadcast` to no avail, but don't really understand what the `WampServerInterface` is supposed to be used for?

Since my own class is a running script, I obviously can't create a new instance of it anywhere else. As my application will be sending user specific updates I need some sort of way to do this following:

Grab the currently connected users using another script, process these somewhere and return any updates they might have, every 60 seconds. Now although this might sound like polling, it would only be one connection doing this and so wouldn't be intensive on the server - at least that's what I think. **So how can I interact my running server script with other "static" PHP scripts elsewhere?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$conn` parameter is a implementation of the [ConnectionInterface](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet/blob/master/src/Ratchet/ConnectionInterface.php) - it has a `send()` method. So that's how you can send messages to the client.

Ratchet (via React.PHP) also [supports timers](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop/blob/master/src/LoopInterface.php). So if there's no external dependency, you can just use `$loop->addPeriodicTimer()` to send messages to every client every 60 seconds.

If you need to send messages based on some external dependencies (like a web server request or a cron script), use ZMQ ([Ratchet docs](http://socketo.me/docs/push)). It's easy.

Check out my [slides about WebSockets in PHP](https://speakerdeck.com/ondrejmirtes/websockety-jak-na-real-time-aplikace-v-php). The notes are in Czech, but you can find the source code examples useful.

Comment: Cheers, `$conn->send('Hello')` worked although I swear I tried it before! Those slides were handy, although only know English :)

Comment: Ah see what you mean now, the docs do explain it but they're pretty poor.

Comment: To save asking another question, any idea what the second parameter is for in getSocket using ZMQContext? I.e. `getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'Pull Notification');` - where is "Pull Notification" used?

Comment: Lol no worries, also any clues on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875497/react-zmq-ratchet-websocket-server-response would be awesome :D

Comment: Didn't finish reading yet, but this: $push->on('Push Notification', array($pusher, 'onNewPush')); -- should be on('message', ...

Comment: If my method returns a value, how do I get that back? I really don't understand this "on" bit :(

Comment: I also have problem with sending message to specific user, I posted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418640/ratchet-send-message-from-server. Problem is i can't get list of connected users from another script