# React/ZMQ/Ratchet - Websocket server response

Tags: php, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

I've currently got a web socket server running and working with Ratchet PHP. I'm not at the stage where I want external scripts to communicate with my server. I can successfully push data to it using ZMQ:

## push.php

```
$json = ['name' => 'Joe Bloggs'];

$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'Push Notification');
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

$socket->send(json_encode($json));
```

Then in my webserver script I can send this to a method (`onNewPush`) to do something with it when the push.php file is run (ran?):

```
...
$push = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$push->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
$push->on('Push Notification', array($pusher, 'onNewPush'));
...
```

So this works fine, but I'm having trouble trying to receive a response back. I'm trying something like:

## pull.php

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ, 'Pull Notification');
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5554");

$socket->send('data');

echo $socket->recv();
```

Then in my server script:

```
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5554');
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onPull'));
```

My `$pusher` variable loads my file which implements a few Ratchet Interfaces. But essentially I'm just returning a string:

```
public function onPull()
{
    return "some data";
}
```

When running `pull.php` I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ZMQSocketException' with message 'Failed to receive message: Not supported' in websockets\pull.php:9 Stack trace: #0 websockets\pull.php(9): ZMQSocket->recv() #1 {main} thrown in websockets\pull.php on line 9
```

Does anyone know why?

Also what importance does the second parameter on `getSocket()` have? Just seems like a string which is never used again.

Cheers

UPDATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pull.php file, you've got a `REQ` socket connecting to a `PULL` socket.  [Check out the docs](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket) to see compatible socket pairs.  In particular, it appears that you want a `REQ-REP` pair so that your client can request data and your server replies with a response.  You'd use `PUSH-PULL` if your server queues up data ready for the next client, and then your client pulls whatever is next from the queue.

In either event, you cannot connect a `REQ` socket to a `PULL` socket or a `PUSH` socket.

I don't fully understand your use case or communication architecture from the listed code or naming scheme, so I don't know how much more detail I can give than that, feel free to clarify what's going on and I might be able to advise more definitively what socket strategy you should be using.

Comment: Yep I decided to do some reading and discovered that last night. I got the REQ REP sequence working, but it only worked once (any other requests from my pull script just hung). Basically my use case is: Have a static PHP script on the same server as the web socket server, and every 30 seconds on a cron job the script gets the currently connected users to my webserver. I decided to write a new question for clarity, no response yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891538/zmq-rep-req-send-receive-not-working

Comment: If you're no longer experiencing the issue in this question, you should accept the answer that solved your problem, or write your own and accept it, so the question doesn't hang out there looking unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your pull.php:

```
echo $socket->recv();
```

Push socket is for sending messages, not receiving them. That's probably where the exception comes from.

Also: The first parameter of method `on()` on pull sockets should be `'message'`.

```
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onPull'));
```

Comment: Thanks again. I updated my pull.php to use `ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL` (can't find any docs on this bit) and removed the `send` part and now my script just executes but doesn't stop. Not sure how to get a response back.. hm.